# VMWare tools install failure. Unable to find "depmod" progam

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

I am getting the following error when running vmware-install.pl.

> Setup is unable to find the "depmod" program on your machine. Please make sure  it is installed. Do you want to specify the location of this program by hand?

I'm running this as root when this occurs. Prior reading has led me to believe that depmod should be in /sbin/depmod, but it is also not there.

VM Software: VMware Workstation

HOST: Windows 10

Guest: debian-10.1.0-386

Any advice or solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per https://www.howtoforge.com/vmware_tools_on_linux

Install the required tools:

`apt-get install autoconf automake binutils cpp gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) make psmisc`

Comment: OMFG. 12 hours of work to get back to the same original error message that started me down this road. `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` does NOT EVER YIELD THE NAME OF AN EXISTING PACKAGE. IT IS NOT SOMETHING THAT IT IS POSSIBLE TO INSTALL. THE PACKAGE FOR THE VALUE THAT $(UNAME-R) RETURNS *DOES NOT EXIST*. My god. This kafkaesque nightmare is never going to end. Another 5AM night. I am sorry for whatever I did in life to deserve this.

Comment: @JohnSmith if your distro doesn't provide a linux-headers- package with your kernel name as the suffix, you'd just need to look at what kernel you are running, and find the required package yourself. Not sure what else I can suggest?

Answer (score 25):

`depmod` and other tools are found inside `/sbin/`. After entering these paths manually when the install script asked for them, it showed me that I should instead use the `open-vm-tools` packages, see http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2073803

This in turn led me to https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/blob/master/README.md which eventually made me realize that they're talking about a package I can install with `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

and

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

After running both, and then rebooting, my VM's screen size finally adjusts to the VM's window size and Copy & Paste works as well.

Comment: ^^ This is the answer. Stop looking elsewhere!.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, vmtools should prompt this suggestion at the first place when user trying to install vmtools on supported OS/platform.

Answer (score 7):

here your solution.

`root@mydebian:~/vmware-tools-distrib# ./vmware-tools-distrib`
This command return ERROR Setup is unable to find the "depmod" program on your machine

`root@mydebian:~/vmware-tools-distrib# sudo ./vmware-tools-distrib`
This command WORK and install vmware tools.

Comment: Why exactly would you need to use sudo if you're root?

Comment: I got this question too . But I should do this question to dev debian 10 it at debian. If u use SUDO with ROOT for launch vmware-tools-distrib alla work perfectly. Next time try and after write me all questions : https://vitux.com/how-to-install-vmware-tools-in-debian-10/

Comment: It dosen't, that's why I'm curious. sudo runs a command as another user, root by default. So why is root pretending too be root

Comment: i don't have all answers, but i post the solution, sure 100% work!

Comment: Wrong. This command does not WORK, it prints the letter 'y' over and over again until you force quit, and that's all it does. It does not install vmware tools, because like literally every single thing I have tried for the past week in linux that I saw on Stack Exchange, it is 100% BROKEN AND NOTHING BUT A WASTE OF TIME TO TRY TO GET TO WORK.

Answer (score 3):

You need depmod installed on your VMware guest machine.

This package is part of kmod https://packages.debian.org/buster/kmod

Use the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install kmod
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to access the root access because it seems you're not logged in as root.
Use this code for root,
sudo -s or sudo -i the input your password.
ones in root access your desktop with this code,
/home/username/Desktop
When in Desktop you can follow up with your installation process.
You wont get the error again

You get this error because you're not root

Answer (score 1):

Works for me : 
ln -s /sbin/depmod /bin/depmod 
ln -s /sbin/modprobe /bin/modprobe 
ln -s /sbin/rmmod    /bin/rmmod

Answer (score -3):

лично мне помогло следующее:

1. заход под root прямо в терминале
2. apt-get install autoconf (он что-то установил)
3. apt-get install open-vm-tools (тоже что-то установил)

после этого экран виртуальной машины стал размера ноутбука, а это верный признак установки vm tools))))

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь, но SuperUser разрешает вопросы и ответы только на английском языке.